# Valign not working in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this kivy file here:

```
<Help>:
    Label:
        text: "[b]Help Page[/b]\n"
        font_size: 30
        markup: True
        valign: "top"
        color: 0,0,0,1
    Label:
        text: "[b] How To Use:[/b]\n"
        font_size: 30
        markup: True
        valign: 'top'
        color: 0,0,0,1
```

However, the text does not go to the top of the page. This is the output:

[image: Output]

What is wrong with this? and may I also ask about how to format those overlapping text. Thanks :)

edit:
This is what I want to happen with the text:

desired output

[image]

So to get that result I tried using the valign and halign to format the text but it does not seem to work. Hope this clarified my question :)

Comment: what is `Help`?

Comment: Help is a screen and should display a help page :)

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get, I think you're going astray, and you're in a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Display Text at Top

To display the text at top using valign: 'top', replace `text_size: root.width, None` with `text_size: root.width, root.height`

### Snippet

```
<Help>:
    Label:
        id: help
        text_size: root.width, root.height
        markup: True
        valign: 'top'
        halign: 'center'
        color: 0,0,0,1
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Text at top]

## Display Both Strings as One

To display both strings, "*How to Operate: Some text here*" and "*Some title Some more text*" as one, we will do the following:

### kv file

```
<Help>:
    Label:
        id: help
        text_size: root.width, None
        markup: True
        halign: 'center'
        color: 0,0,0,1
```

### Python Code

```
class Help(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.help.text = "[size=30][b]How to Operate[/b][/size]\nSome text here" + \
                             "\n\n[size=30][b]Some title[/b][/size]\nSome more text"
```

## Output - Combined Text

[image: Img01 - Combined Text]

## Text Overlapping

The Label's text are overlapping because you are adding two Label widgets on-top each other in a Screen Layout.

Add a BoxLayout as parent of the two Label widgets to prevent text overlapping.

## Text Wrapping

Wraps the text at a certain width, provide the width. For example, a Label to be created in a box with width=200 and unlimited height.

```
Label(text='Very big big line', text_size=(200, None))
```

### Snippet

```
<Help>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text_size: dp(230), None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: "[size=30][b]How to Operate[/b][/size]Some text here"
            markup: True
            valign: "top"
            halign: 'center'
            color: 0,0,0,1

        Label:
            text_size: dp(150), None
            text: "[size=30][b]Some title[/b][/size]Some more text"
            markup: True
            valign: 'top'
            halign: 'center'
            color: 0,0,0,1
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

## Text Alignment

Add `text_size: self.size`

### Snippet

```
<Help>:
    Label:
        text_size: self.size
        text: "[b]Help Page[/b]\n"
        font_size: 30
        markup: True
        valign: "top"
        color: 0,0,0,1
    Label:
        text_size: self.size
        text: "[b] How To Use:[/b]\n"
        font_size: 30
        markup: True
        valign: 'top'
        color: 0,0,0,1
```

[Text alignment and wrapping](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#text-alignment-and-wrapping)

> In order for the [halign](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.halign) and [valign](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.valign) alignment properties to
>   take effect, set the [text_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size), which specifies the size of the
>   bounding box within which text is aligned.

## Output

[image: Img02]

Comment: The solution works but what if for example i want a text right below the "how to operate" text how would I do that?

Comment: And can I not combine the both so that I can format it as well as not letting the text overlap?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to display both strings,  "*How to Operate: Some text here*" and "*Some title Some more text*" as one i.e. using only one Label widget.

Comment: Well the halign works but when I set it the valign to 'top' it still remains in the center. does it mean that I can only use halign here and not valign?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to display text at top.